# Setting Azure API access permissions not recognizing other API's

Tags: visual-studio, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I followed this tutorial to create a aspnet core web api using Azure for a test project I'm working on:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore

The instructions says "Configure Permissions for your application - in the Settings menu, choose the 'Required permissions' section, click on Add, then Select an API, and type 'TodoListService' in the textbox. Then, click on Select Permissions and select 'Access TodoListService'"

I followed every step closely and most was on target with everything, but this step didn't show my todolist service.Below is the screenshots in the order I did them.

**Navigate to the apps page**
[image]

**Go to settings and required permissions for either app**
[image]

**Click add at the top left hand corner to add a new permission**
[image]

**To Do List Service and To Do List Web App are not listed**
[image]

The tutorial worked for the most part. I am able to run the VS solution and sign in to an azure account associated with my application. However the users don't have read permissions to the to do list on the website, and I think it is because I had to skip this step.

**After logging in through MS**

[image]

**Shows logged in**
[image]

**User cant view the to do list**
[image]

As you can see I am clearly logged in, but am not able to see the list

Comment: Hmm, could be a problem with the new portal.. Have you tried creating the app in the old portal instead?

Comment: Ive never used Azure before the new portal, I wouldnt think this would be a cause of this

Comment: Actually there is a problem that the Service Principal for the app is not created until you log in: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2016/10/04/provision-an-app-created-on-portal-azure-com-in-your-own-tenant/ Check there for a small utility for creating the principal. Otherwise, you have to setup the permission in the service's manifest manually.

Comment: On the tutorial it sets the port of the service api to https://localhost:44351 but the web application is https://localhost:44371/signin-oidc I wonder if that has something to do with it

Comment: The reply URL of course has to match whatever you have.

Comment: Wouldnt the Service API be on a seperate port though? I looked at that website, my web app seems fine (the todolist app) the web service (todolist service) doesnt seem to be set up where I can just "touch" the site by logging in as he says. The service doesnt have a sign in page. It has that "Log on to the app to create a local instance" error

Comment: There in the part where you search for the API to require a permission there, have you tried searching by typing something like Todo in the box?